# CAS 6.6.6 customize login webflow to open custom dashboard view

Tags: single-sign-on, cas, apereo

I am using CAS-6.6.6 by using maven and I am trying to change landing page (if no service found) to my customized JSP view. I can't use same location for custom page hence, need to update webflow to add my custom view. Please suggest. Even If there is any way to update webflow by using xml (as CAS 6.6.X not supports xml based webflows), I can work with that too. Thanks.

I have tried customizing login webflow but it always open default dashboard.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to open my own custom dashboard after successful login which will have links of different application.

Comment: I have written one customWebflowConfigurer which extends AbstractCasWebflowConfigurer and in doInitialize() method I have written below code to open my dashboard page but not succeeded. It always open default dashboard (as there is no service found to redirect to):

Comment: `code`
final Flow flow = getLoginFlow();
 ActionState actionState = (ActionState) flow.getState(CasWebflowConstants.STATE_ID_SEND_TICKET_GRANTING_TICKET);
   actionState.getEntryActionList().add(createEvaluateAction(CasWebflowConstants.ACTION_ID_SEND_TICKET_GRANTING_TICKET));
   
Transition customFlowCheckTransition= createTransition(CasWebflowConstants.STATE_ID_SUCCESS, "customFlowCheck");
   actionState.getTransitionSet().add(customFlowCheckTransition);
   
`code`

Comment: So, I have resolved the issue by modifying the code as below:


`code`

ActionState actionState = (ActionState) flow.getState(CasWebflowConstants.STATE_ID_SEND_TICKET_GRANTING_TICKET);
  actionState.getEntryActionList()
    .add(createEvaluateAction(CasWebflowConstants.ACTION_ID_SEND_TICKET_GRANTING_TICKET));

  final ViewState customDashboardView = createViewState(flow, "customDashboardView",
    getViewFactory("nucleus/dashboard"));
  customDashboardView.getEntryActionList().add(createEvaluateAction("customDashboardViewAction"));

`code`

Comment: `code`

final EndState state = createEndState(flow, "customDashboardState", "nucleus/dashboard");
  logger.debug("viewGenericLoginSuccess.getEntryActionList() size {}", state.getEntryActionList().size());
  state.getEntryActionList().add(createEvaluateAction(CasWebflowConstants.ACTION_ID_GENERIC_SUCCESS_VIEW));

  Transition customDashboardTransition = createTransitionForState(actionState,
    CasWebflowConstants.STATE_ID_SUCCESS, "customDashboardState", true);
  actionState.getTransitionSet().add(customDashboardTransition);

`code`

Comment: Now, I have a new situation that I need to open my service applications (other external applications registered with CAS as service) by clicking link on the dashboard page. Also need to show some user data on my dashboard. Please help me to get the solution.